# When is code shared for different instantiations of generics in the CLR?

Tags: c#, generics, clr, value-type

If you have a method or type `Foo<T>`, then the CLR may compile multiple versions for different T. I know that all reference types share the same version. How does it work for structs? Is code sometimes shared, or never shared, for different structs? I could imagine that code is shared for all structs of the same size, for example.

I'm interested because I'm wondering about the following example:

```
interface IBar 
{
   void DoBar();
}

struct Baz : IBar 
{
   public void DoBar(){ ... }
}

struct Quux : IBar 
{
   public void DoBar(){ ... }
}
```

Now if I do the following:

```
public void ExecuteBar<T>(T bar) where T:IBar
{
   bar.DoBar();
}

ExecuteBar(new Baz());
ExecuteBar(new Quux());
```

Will this generate two versions of `ExecuteBar`, each with a direct (non virtual) call directly to `Bar.DoBar()` and `Quux.DoBar()`? Or is the dispatch done at run time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no straight-forward answer to this question, it greatly depends on the jitter you use and what kind of code is present in the generic method.

A starting point is that the jitter does generate a distinct method for each individual value type.  Even for structs that are otherwise completely identical.  Something you can see with the debugger.  Use Debug + Windows + Disassembly to see the generated machine code.  Single step into a method, use the Debug + Windows + Registers window, the EIP/RIP register shows you the location of the method in memory.

But, generic methods like this are still eligible for the inlining optimization.  Very important to perf, it makes the entire method disappear and the code in the method is injected into the caller method.  In which case the distinction between generic methods *does* disappear.  This is not something you can normally count on to happen for interface implementation methods.  It does however happen for your sample code if you leave the method bodies empty.  With different results for the x86 and the x64 jitter.

You can only really tell what you get by looking at the generated machine code.  Do make sure that you allow the optimizer to do its job, Tools + Options, Debugging, General, untick the "Suppress JIT optimization" checkbox.  And, of course, do make sure that you *never* depend on an accurate answer to this question.  Implementation details like this are subject to change without notice.

Comment: Correct. So I guess that, on the level the asker is interested in, the answer is: The former alternative, two different methods are created, one for each of the value types, and the dispatch is non-virtual.

Comment: Thanks! @Jeppe: yes indeed. It may be the case that the code is further optimized by inlining, and that would be even more efficient, but I was interested in the baseline performance model of interface calls on structs whose type is explicitly passed as a parameter to a generic method or class. I know that you shouldn't rely on this behavior, but it can serve as a starting point for optimization. If a dispatch is slowing down the code, it may be worth changing a class to a struct to eliminate the dispatch.

Answer (score 1):

The generic definitions are not directly used. Instead constructed types are created at runtime.

One construct will be created for each value type argument. A unique construct will be created for all reference types arguments.

Afaik, different types do not share the same asm instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I put your code into LINQPad and the generated IL shows that there is only one version of ExcuteBar which calls IBar.DoBar()

```
ExecuteBar:
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldarga.s    01 
IL_0003:  constrained. 01 00 00 1B 
IL_0009:  callvirt    UserQuery+IBar.DoBar
IL_000E:  nop         
IL_000F:  ret
```

Method ExecuteBar2(IBar bar) looks similar:

```
ExecuteBar2:
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldarg.1     
IL_0002:  callvirt    UserQuery+IBar.DoBar
IL_0007:  nop         
IL_0008:  ret
```

Edit:

```
class C : IBar {
   public void DoBar(){}
}
```

Reference type is passed as argument into the same method(s) (Baz and Quux are boxed)

Comment: At the IL level, sure. But notice that constrained prefix. My question is what the CLR does with that, not what the C# compiler does with it.